# Where does mounting/dismounting start/end?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mounted-combat

I want to get on my mount. Where should my character be for this to be possible? I initially thought being in any adjacent square was enough but I've read [an article for 3.5](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20050125a) which suggests you need to share a square momentarily.

The rules don't seem to say anything about position. Is there an official stance on this I have missed? If not, what would people suggest for this?

Comment: I think being adjacent should be enough but I have to ask.Why is it significant?

Comment: Probably not overly significant, but if you dismount in one of a horse's squares, you would have to move into an empty square before doing anything, which may provoke unless you 5-foot step. Also, the 5 extra feet needed to enter a mount's square to mount may be the difference between mounting this turn or the next if you're 5 feet too far.

Comment: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity  in here if you take a look at Table: Actions in Combat, under move action section it is stated that mounting/dismounting does not provoke attack of opportunity

Comment: @Trajan: Said article is here http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20050125a. See "Mounting & Dismounting".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m reasonably certain that the rules never say. So far as I can tell, it seems you can just... use a move action to mount something. There’s nothing saying you have to be anywhere near it at all, which is dumb. (For that matter, I also don’t see any rules about the mount having to be OK with you getting on, which is also dumb. Though you do presumably still provoke from that creature for entering its square, which one way or another you have to do to wind up mounted.)

So I don’t think the rules are going to work here. To me, it seems most sense that you can only mount a creature while sharing that creature’s square. Since mounting is a move action, this works out to being almost the same thing as mounting from any adjacent square, since you can five-foot step into the mount’s square and then mount up (remember, you can five-foot step and use a move action in the same round; the restriction is that you cannot five-foot step and use a move action *to move* in the same round). Note also that DC 20 Ride check can allow you to mount as a free action, which means you can then mount in one turn from greater distances (using your move to reach the square and then mounting as a free action).

Comment: "Dumb" can also be interpreted as "goes without needing to be said..." It doesn't say there has to be a mount!  It doesn't say it can't be size Tiny or Colossal!  It... Assumes a human being is playing it!